# How to center the links in mobile view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<div id="DonorLinks">
            <hr>
            <ul id="donorLinkSection" class="nav nav-justified">
                <li id="IntroVideo" class="navLinks">
                    <a id="DonorIntroVideoLink" href="/" onclick="return someFunction()">
                        <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>Watch introductory video
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="PgmDetails" class="navLinks"><a id="PgmDetailsPageLink" href="DonorDetails"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>View program details</a></li>
                <li id="TestimonialLink" class="navLinks"><a id="TestimonialPageLink" href="DonorTestimonials"><i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>See what nonprofits say</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            </div>
```

Hi, the above HTML gives the following arrangement of URL in Desktop View and Mobile View

I have used nav-justified class to justify the links in both desktop view and mobile view. While the desktop view is just fine (Three links appearing horizontally), In mobile view the 2nd link is slightly misaligned (links have to appear vertically). Is there a cleaner way to align the links in mobile view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***answer updated***

you can now individually give margin-right to your second link `#PgmDetails`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css">

<style>
#PgmDetails { margin-right: 22px; } <!-- as per your need-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="DonorLinks">
            <hr>
            <ul id="donorLinkSection" class="nav nav-justified">
                <li id="IntroVideo" class="navLinks">
                    <a id="DonorIntroVideoLink" href="/" onclick="return someFunction()">
                        <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>Watch introductory video
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="PgmDetails" class="navLinks"><a id="PgmDetailsPageLink" href="DonorDetails"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>View program details</a></li>
                <li id="TestimonialLink" class="navLinks"><a id="TestimonialPageLink" href="DonorTestimonials"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>See what nonprofits say</a></li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Maulik, really appreciate it. But let's try to position the URL in the center while maintaining the same left alignment.

Comment: @Purushottam.Prasad you can check now my updated answer : )

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   some text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Try like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think glyphicon used extra padding or margin in your code.
just update

`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt ml-0 pl-0" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

or you can inspect element so that you can see where is that extra padding

Comment: Hi Maulik. There is same amount of padding for all three glyphicon. However I think the misalignment has something to do with the length of the text as when I increase the length of the text the URL's get perfectly aligned. So, could we have some way around for this ?

Comment: @Purushottam.Prasad are those 3 links is in left side in mobile view?? if yes then you can add text-left class

Answer (score 0):

I think your using Bootstrap. We can use flex-column class [Reference link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#working-with-flex-utilities)

Comment: Thanks for the answer prime417 but adding flex column will distort the horizontal alignment in desktop view.